# asp.net httpContext session pipeline

Tags: asp.net

I want to use HttpContext.Current.Items while my request is active and store a hashtable in it until the end of the request.

I need to know where in the Global.asax file I can add the HttpContext.Current.items(ht) into the session...

I have tried MANY different areas in the ASAX, with no luck.

This is an ASP.NET 3.5 app, but 95% of the calls are made with AJAX - in case that makes a difference...

Thanx
Jerry

Comment: Do you use ASP.NET webforms or ASP.NET MVC? This makes the difference...

Comment: I'm going to be using SQL Server as my state server and recently found out that session objects must be serializable.  I thought if I stored the session vars in a hashtable & retrieved them @ the beginning of each request, then, throughout the request, added/removed them from w/in the HttpContext.Current.Items, then finally, when all of my processing was complete, add the hashtable in the HttpContext.Current.Items to session - I'd make less trips to SQL...but I can't figure out where in the ASAX this should occur.

Comment: Are you refer to the IHttpModule? Its been accessed everytime a httprequest occur. You can parse querystrings, block or filter sessions i.e. ip or document types. The module have to be registered in web/app.config to run.

Answer (score 1):

How about the PostRequestHandlerExecute event, such as here:

```
 public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
{

    void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Items.Add("ht", new System.Collections.Hashtable());
    }

    protected void Application_PostRequestHandlerExecute(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpContext.Current.Session.Add("ht", HttpContext.Current.Items["ht"]);
    }
}
```

That event should fire once your HttpHander has finished processing the request